# Not able to create AD HOC network

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, network-monitoring, mesh

I am trying to create an adhoc network with following command in ubuntu 16.04:

> sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid my-mesh-network ap 02:12:34:56:78:9A channel 1

however when I try to enable the interface, its giving me error

> sudo ip link set up dev wlan0
>   **output:**
>   rtnetlink answers device or resource busy

This problem comes only when the interface mode is set to "Ad-Hoc"
In `monitor` mode or `managed` mode, this issue does not come.

Can you please tell me if this issue is due to the driver limitation or I am missing anything.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> "rtnetlink answers device or resource busy"

I think it means exactly what it says. The device  *wlan0* is busy sending and recieving data to your router or access point, getting email, etc. I suggest that you tell it to stop:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

And try again:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid my-mesh-network ap 02:12:34:56:78:9A channel 1
```

If you have Network Manager running, you will probably need to stop it first:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Comment: thanks @chili555, stopping the network-manager service helped.

Comment: I cannot `ifconfig wlan0 up` after configure ad-hoc

Comment: @KingStone Please start your own new question and include more details.